# Insert Inner HTML from drop down menu into new table row

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I click the button labeled *add Row* that works just fine, but when I click the button labeled *Assign*, I want it to assign the variables that are selected into the appropriate row and cells but for some reason it changes only the top row. I am somewhat new at JavaScript.

```js
function myFunction() {

    var table = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var row = table.insertRow(2);
    
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(0);
    
    cell6.innerHTML = ' <button onclick="myFunction1()"> Assign </button> ';
    cell5.innerHTML = " A ";
    cell4.innerHTML = " B ";
 cell3.innerHTML = ' <center id="demo1"> ';
 cell2.innerHTML = ' <center id="demo2"> ';
 cell1.innerHTML = ' <center id="demo3"> ';
    
}


             function myFunction1() { 
                 var a = document.getElementById("select1");
                 var b = document.getElementById("select2");
                 var c = document.getElementById("select3");
                 
        var x1 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;
                 var x2 = b.options[b.selectedIndex].text;
                 var x3 = c.options[c.selectedIndex].text;
                     
                  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x1;
                  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x2;
                  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x3;}
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<h5> <b> SELECT SORT VARIABLES FOR STRATUM </b></h5>
<h1> </h1>
<div class="unselected-field" style="display: inline-block; position: left;" >
<h1> </h1>
    <span> SORT VARIABLE 1: </span>
 <select id="select1" name="SORTONE" value="EMPLOYMENT">
    <option> EMPLOYMENT </option>
     <option> WAGES </option>
 </select>

 <h1> </h1> 
  <span>SORT VARIABLE 2: </span>
 <select id="select2" name="SORTTWO" value="NONE">
 <option> NONE </option>
    <option> EMPLOYMENT </option>
     <option> WAGES </option>
 </select>
 
 <h1></h1>
 <span>SORT VARIABLE 3: </span>
 <select id="select3" name="SORTTHREE" value="NONE">
 <option> NONE </option>
    <option> EMPLOYMENT </option>
     <option> WAGES </option>
 </select>
<h1></h1>

<table  id="Table1" align="right" style="margin:2% 10% auto;">
             <tr>
             <th bgcolor="grey"> ASSIGN </th>
             <th bgcolor="grey"> SS </th>
             <th bgcolor="grey"> DESCRIPTION </th>
             <th bgcolor="grey"> SORT ORDER 1 </th>
             <th bgcolor="grey"> SORT ORDER 2 </th>
             <th bgcolor="grey" > SORT ORDER 3 </th>
             </tr>
             <tr><td> <button onclick="myFunction1()"> Assign </button> </td>
             <td><center> -- </center> </td>
             <td> DEFAULT SINGLE </td>
             <td> <center id="demo1"> </td>
             <td> <center id="demo2"> </td> 
             <td> <center id="demo3"> </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()"> Add New Row </button>
```

Comment: Greetings, this is not a good fit for codereview. We work on completed, working code. I voted to close this question and migrate it to stackoverflow which is a good fit this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation for the [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute:

> The **id** global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)</sup>

So each element needs to have a unique *id* attribute. One solution is to utilize the *class* attribute instead of the *id* attribute. So lines like these:

> ```
> <td> <center id="demo1"> </td>
> <td> <center id="demo2"> </td> 
> <td> <center id="demo3"> </td>
> ```

Get updated like this:

```
<td> <center class="demo1"> </td>
<td> <center class="demo2"> </td> 
<td> <center class="demo3"> </td>
```

And similarly in the function `myFunction()` which adds the new row:

```
cell3.innerHTML = ' <center class="demo1"> ';
cell2.innerHTML = ' <center class="demo2"> ';
cell1.innerHTML = ' <center class="demo3"> ';
```

Then pass the *event* argument in the [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) handlers to the function1:

```
<button onclick="myFunction1(event)"> Assign </button>
```

And similarly in when adding a new row:

```
cell6.innerHTML = ' <button onclick="myFunction1(event)"> Assign </button> ';
```

And accept it in that function arguments:

```
function myFunction1(clickEvent) {
```

Then use it to find the row containing the button labeled *Assign*:

```
var target = clickEvent.target;
//ascend up the DOM-tree until we find the table row
while (target.tagName.toUpperCase() != "TR") {
    target = target.parentNode;
}
```

Then update the elements with the class names by utilizing [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) (which returns an array, so take the 1st element) instead of [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

```
target.getElementsByClassName("demo1")[0].innerHTML = x1;
target.getElementsByClassName("demo2")[0].innerHTML = x2;
target.getElementsByClassName("demo3")[0].innerHTML = x3;
```

Expand the snippet below for a demonstration:

```js
function myFunction() {

  var table = document.getElementById("Table1");
  var row = table.insertRow(2);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(0);

  cell6.innerHTML = ' <button onclick="myFunction1(event)"> Assign </button> ';
  cell5.innerHTML = " A ";
  cell4.innerHTML = " B ";
  cell3.innerHTML = ' <center class="demo1"> ';
  cell2.innerHTML = ' <center class="demo2"> ';
  cell1.innerHTML = ' <center class="demo3"> ';

}


function myFunction1(clickEvent) {
  var target = clickEvent.target;
  while (target.tagName.toUpperCase() != "TR") {
    target = target.parentNode;
  }

  var a = document.getElementById("select1");
  var b = document.getElementById("select2");
  var c = document.getElementById("select3");

  var x1 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;
  var x2 = b.options[b.selectedIndex].text;
  var x3 = c.options[c.selectedIndex].text;

  target.getElementsByClassName("demo1")[0].innerHTML = x1;
  target.getElementsByClassName("demo2")[0].innerHTML = x2;
  target.getElementsByClassName("demo3")[0].innerHTML = x3;
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<h5> <b> SELECT SORT VARIABLES FOR STRATUM </b></h5>
<h1> </h1>
<div class="unselected-field" style="display: inline-block; position: left;">
  <h1> </h1>
  <span> SORT VARIABLE 1: </span>
  <select id="select1" name="SORTONE" value="EMPLOYMENT">
    <option> EMPLOYMENT </option>
     <option> WAGES </option>
 </select>

  <h1> </h1>
  <span>SORT VARIABLE 2: </span>
  <select id="select2" name="SORTTWO" value="NONE">
 <option> NONE </option>
    <option> EMPLOYMENT </option>
     <option> WAGES </option>
 </select>

  <h1></h1>
  <span>SORT VARIABLE 3: </span>
  <select id="select3" name="SORTTHREE" value="NONE">
 <option> NONE </option>
    <option> EMPLOYMENT </option>
     <option> WAGES </option>
 </select>
  <h1></h1>

  <table id="Table1" align="right" style="margin:2% 10% auto;">
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="grey"> ASSIGN </th>
      <th bgcolor="grey"> SS </th>
      <th bgcolor="grey"> DESCRIPTION </th>
      <th bgcolor="grey"> SORT ORDER 1 </th>
      <th bgcolor="grey"> SORT ORDER 2 </th>
      <th bgcolor="grey"> SORT ORDER 3 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <button onclick="myFunction1(event)"> Assign </button> </td>
      <td>
        <center> -- </center>
      </td>
      <td> DEFAULT SINGLE </td>
      <td>
        <center class="demo1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <center class="demo2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <center class="demo3">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()"> Add New Row </button>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew there was an issue with the unique names but could not see how to code it.